# Asking for login even after passing credentials in webclient

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, web-scraping

I'm trying to download file from an url. But even after giving network credentials the file downloaded will be of login page.

```
WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
            NetworkCredential myCred = new NetworkCredential(
"username", "password", "abc.com");
            downloader.Credentials = myCred;
            downloader.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(downloader_DownloadFileCompleted);
            downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(downloader_DownloadProgressChanged);
            downloader.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), "C://Desktop/File_extracted.doc");
```

This is the code i'm using to download file. How to get the file in that url.

Comment: It depends on the authentication method used by this website. If it uses forms authentication then probably you need to gain an authentication cookie first and then use this cookie for file downloading.

Comment: Thank you Mike for reply, how to know which type of authentication is being used in a web site.

Comment: You may know it by analysing http traffic (using Firebug or other tool). But I think as long as the website redirects you to a login page it means it uses forms authentication.